# Open SSL Can't open config.txt for reading, No such file or directory 13056:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No

Tags: openssl

Can't open config.txt for reading, No such file or directory
13056:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('config.txt','r')
13056:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:76:

[screenshot cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngONG.png)
[screenshot folder & config.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpcfN.png)

i follow this guy step https://youtu.be/f9ZadlfSIDI
first step but i can't continue

the code on cmd

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost_android.crt -keyout localhost_android.key -newkey rsa:2048 -days 1024 -nodes -sha256 -subj "/C=US/O=Dev-Certificate/CN=Ryudith" -extensions EXT -config config.txt
```

i already add path on environment variable

how do i solve this?
any answer i really appreciate